# vuetify 3 v-autocomplete select all text on focus

Tags: vuejs3, vuetify.js, vuetifyjs3

I'm attempting to select all text on a `v-autocomplete` vuetify 3 component when a user tabs into or selects the component so they can immediately start editing the value but I'm having issues doing this with code like the following:

```
<v-autocomplete
    label="Customer"
    @focus="OnCustomerFocus"
></v-autocomplete>

methods: {
    OnCustomerFocus(event: any) {
      console.log('customer focused');
      console.log(event);
      event.target.select();
    },
  }
```

Here is a sandbox version of what I'm trying to accomplish without success:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/cwerner-vuetify-3-v-autocomplete-select?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FShipment.vue

It appears at one time this was the default behavior of a `v-autocomplete` but it was removed at one point according to this github article:

https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/discussions/13562

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vuetify seems to shows the underlying input only during editing, and when the `focus` event is trigger, the input is still hidden, causing `.select()` to not work. You have to wait until the input is visible with `nextTick()`:

```
async onCustomerFocus(event: any) {
  await nextTick()
  event.target.select();
}
```

Here it is in a [playground](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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)